# PDF compressor for DELPHI 2007

Tags: delphi, pdf, delphi-2007, vcl

Need a PDF compressor that I can use from DELPHI 2007.

What is the best one out there?

UPDATE ---

By PDF compressor I mean some way to compress an existing PDF. I don’t need to create new PDF files.

The usage that I’ll do with it, simple, I have in my applications the possibility to associate a file to a product, an entity, equipment whatever, and if the file is a PDF I want to be able reduce its size.

There some tools that can do this with no need to actually zip the file, what would mean that to see it you would have to decompress(unzip), this tools jut reduce the size.

So a PDF compressor, or call it what you will, is just this.

Comment: What do you call a PDF compressor? Something to make pdf file smaller?

Comment: @Jlouro you'll only get a helpful answer if you actually tell us what you mean by PDF compressor and some more details of what you will do with such a thing. At the moment this question is not answerable and with the lack of clarification from you, I move to close.

Comment: It may sound strange to you but I have life. I don’t seat in from of the computer waiting for answer, and I don’t expect you to wait for new questions to have some fun. It Saturday get out, meat some people …

Comment: `meat some people` like `having an old friend for dinner`? ;-)

Comment: Jlouro If you ask a question here, it's best to do so first thing in your day and be prepared to contribute during a day. Otherwise you'll lose the moment. If you want to have fun on a Saturday, and good for you if you do, then ask your question on a different day!! You'll get better answers that way!

Comment: As for compressing your PDF, I can only assume you mean by compressing the images. You won't compress text much in PDF. It's easiest to compress the images as you build the PDF. Where do your PDFs come from? Do you make them or do they just appear from some unspecified external source?

Comment: Actually: PDF already compresses text; from what I recollect, image compression depends on the PDF image quality you define.

Comment: @David the question is perfectly clear -- PDF format supports compression, and this compression lets one compress data streams inside (no matter if it's text or images). There's one issue though - compression is usually not offered as a separate operation but only as a step in PDF generation. I guess we'll make it available as a separate one in our SecureBlackbox.

Comment: @eugene compressing the streams is one strand to this. But you can also resample the images to achieve significant size reductions. What's more my question about when in the process the compression is to occur still seems relevant.

Comment: @David I don't say the question is irrelevant, I just thought that you voted to close the question as "not a real question".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to create PDF from Delphi code, see [this page in Delphi:about](http://delphi.about.com/od/toppicks/tp/aatppdf.htm).

I'd like to add [our Open Source SynPdf unit](http://synopse.info/forum/viewforum.php?id=1), working from Delphi 6 up to XE.

Comment: +1; I totally forgot about SynPDF. Out of curiosity: how well does it adhere to the PDF standard? I might need something that extracts TIFF or PNG from PDF pages, and do some page offset/size changes.

Comment: The question was not clear when I answered it. SynPDF was written following the PDF reference document, and should "adhere to the pdf standard". But its purpose is to create pdf, so there is no pdf loader yet. For pdf creating, it's quite complete and tested (e.g. it supports arabic languages, whereas most pdf writer don't). But it can't be used as such for pdf "compressing", because there is no pdf parser yet. Since all pdf objects types do exist in the class hierarchy, it's possible to make it read any pdf file. I don't have time to write a parse. Open source contributions are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Arguably the best is the [Acrobat family of software from Adobe itself](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat.html).

**Edit 2:**

Adobe has quite some [extensive documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat.html) on their API and [docs on their Acrobat.com services](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/acds/C.+API+Reference).
Their Acrobat products are in use by a lot of vendors, even the affordable ones, to provide PDF support.

**Edit 1:**

*Downvoters: it is for two reasons I mentioned `Arguably` in my original answer.

First of all just stating `best` without adding more criteria will always get a subjective answer.

Second: Adobe is the inventor of PDF, and the PDF support of their software is great. I know there are drawbacks of Adobe software too, but the question was the 'best', which I interpreted as the best PDF support.*

Comment: No idea could be worst than this. Acrobat is both monstrous and overpriced, not saying that Adobe's licensing and purchasing policy is next to useless in many regions (consider OP's location)

Comment: +1 There's a lot wrong with Adobe in general, but their PDF technology is good.

Comment: @Eugene: I flagged your comment for moderator attention.

Comment: @Jeroen His comment is neither noise, offensive, or spam. Don't do that. Also, down-voted for a useless answer. You didn`t even link to some kind of developer API.

Comment: @Andrew: I consider monstrous, overpriced, and useless to be rude, especially from a competing vendor (Eugene works for the company that sells PDFBlackbox as part of SecureBlackbox). I personally have had good experience with the Acrobat API. Thanks for your time though. It helps shining some light on two different sides of a story.

Comment: @meagar: thanks for pointing out the missing docs link. I added two links.

Comment: @Jeroen Don't flag comments because you think they're rude. Flag them if they're actually offensive/spam/noise.

Comment: @meagar: Wanting to learn (especially as English not being my native language): what is the thin line between rude and offensive? Maybe we should take this to meta.

Comment: @Jeroen When you flag a question as offensive, the text reads "This question contains content that a reasonable person would consider offensive, abusive, or hate speech" and flagging comments is meant to cover the same ground; senselessly offensive as opposed to impolite. The language is ambiguous but generally "rude" doesn't qualify.

Comment: @Andrew Moore: 10k doesn't make you a moderator.

Comment: @Jeroen: Eugene **didn't mention his products in any of the comments or answers on this question**. Quite frankly, I can't blame him for having the opinion he has. Using Acrobat in your software means that you are adding a 500$ US overhead to the price of your software license per copy. That's a lot of money when they are alternatives are there which are a fraction of the price.

Comment: @Eugene (et al), see [Is it offensive if a competitor of a vendor calls that that vendor “worst, monstrous, overpriced, useless”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76037/is-it-offensive-if-a-competitor-of-a-vendor-calls-that-that-vendor-worst-monstr) which is about your first comment.

Comment: Regarding Acrobat - my downvote was not claiming that Acrobat by iteself is bad, but that the advice to use it is not a good idea, and the reasons are that Acrobat is too pricey and huge for most uses. This was an explanation of my downvote. Now, as we have to deal with Acrobat to make our software compatible with it, I know a lot of it's technical downsides, non-compliance to their own standards (at least in digital security aspects) etc.; and also I know about troubles with licensing it in different countries. So this is my "expert judgment", not an subjective opinion.

Comment: @Eugene: +1; Thanks for clarifying the reasons of your first comment. This indeed makes much more sense.

Comment: @Jeroen what was the *main* thing that you didn't like in my comment - was it the word "monstrous" or the overall post? I am asking cause if it was the word, then please see above comments - this word has many meanings and the whole topic can be a matter of misunderstanding.

Comment: @Eugene: monstrous was one thing, but the main thing was the combination of the italicized words in my question above without explaining why. I probably should have commented that when marking your comment for moderator attention. I wish that the flag had a way to tell moderators about the 'why' of flagging a comment (and I wish there were both upvote and downvote possibilities on comments).

Answer (score 0):

There is an [on-line PDF compressor](http://convert.neevia.com/pdfcompress/) that I heard is giving good results.
It should not be too hard to wrap that in Delphi for occasional use.